# Remove styles from open SELECT elements in Chrome?

Tags: css, forms, google-chrome, accessibility, usability

The current stable version of Chrome (v61) exhibits some undesirable behaviour with styled `select` elements. If you increase the font size of the element via CSS, its "opened" state in Chrome *also* inherits these increased font sizes ([working example](https://codepen.io/markedup/pen/gGKzgv)).

This is not exhibited by other browsers – e.g. Firefox v59 – and makes styled `select` elements in Chrome difficult to use.

Is there a way to remove the styling from the revealed options when the `select` is "opened" just in Chrome? Using `:focus` has no apparent effect.

Comment: Not sure that I'm understanding the problem -- Are you trying to make the text on the collapsed select element larger while keeping the text of the option elements smaller?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily set the `font-size` for the `option` element back to the default html font size:

```
option {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't have the desired effect. I need to keep the large font for the "collapsed" state, to match the prescribed UI design, but the expanded menu should show the `option` text at the browser's default size. Using the `:focus` modifier to target the `option` elements and set them to `1rem` introduces an undesirable collapsing effect to the layout of the `select` until the user clicks away (i.e. deselects the `select` once more).

Comment: @markedup The behavior you described (*I need to keep the large font for the "collapsed" state, to match the prescribed UI design, but the expanded menu should show the option text at the browser's default size.*) is exactly what this does. I have not used the `:focus` modifier. You just have to copy and paste the code in your code.

Comment: I agree with Adam. This produces the OP's specified behavior for me.

Comment: @adam @josh In Chrome, I see no difference adding the above; `option` font sizing remains as big as the applied 'closed' styling to the parent `select`.

Comment: Given that @Adam and I are both seeing the same thing, I wonder if there is some difference in our environments (as opposed to yours). What operating system are you using? Just FYI -- here's a screen capture of what I'm seeing:  https://snag.gy/ZLnPAj.jpg